# AWS Session Manager in docker output ^@ indefinitely

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssm

I've build a custom docker image from python:3.6 with awscli and session manager:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -U awscli
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install groff less curl -y && \
    curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/session-manager-downloads/plugin/latest/ubuntu_64bit/session-manager-plugin.deb" -o "session-manager-plugin.deb" && \
    dpkg -i session-manager-plugin.deb && \
    rm -f session-manager-plugin.deb

RUN curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/session-manager-downloads/plugin/latest/ubuntu_64bit/session-manager-plugin.deb" -o "session-manager-plugin.deb" && \
    dpkg -i session-manager-plugin.deb && \
    rm -f session-manager-plugin.deb

ENTRYPOINT ["aws"]
```

I've created a custom executable file under `/usr/bin/aws`:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":"/app" -v "/root/.aws/":"/root/.aws" python-aws "$@"
```

When I run `aws ssm start-session --target i-***` the output is:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
...
```

Do you know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution will writing the question.

I added `-it` (interactive) to the `docker run` command.

So the the command is now:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd)":"/app" -v "/root/.aws/":"/root/.aws" python-aws "$@"
```

Problem solved.